# webpack: PurfiyCSSPlugin does not include styles referenced by bundle.js

Tags: webpack, purifycss

I try to use webpacks [PurifyCSSPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/purifycss-webpack). My config looks like this

```
new PurifyCSSPlugin({
    paths: glob.sync([
          path.join(env.outputDirectory, './*.html'),
          path.join(env.outputDirectory, './**/*.js'),
          path.join(__dirname, './**/*.tsx')
        ]),
    purifyOptions: {
        info: true,
        minify: false
    }
})
```

and I use styles in this way:

```
import { title } from "./styles.scss";
...
return <h1  className={title}>Hello!</h1>;
```

(the entire project can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/stephanpelikan/javaee-preact-archetype/tree/PurifyCSSPlugin/src/main/frontend)).

The problems I have are

1. If run the build for the first time at get this output:

   PurifyCSS has reduced the file size by ~ 99.4%

   and the page is not correctly rendered because style references within tsx/jsx are missing (or transitive style dependencies).
2. If I run the build for the second time then I get this output:

   PurifyCSS has reduced the file size by ~ 93.2%

   and the page is correctly rendered. My paths settings causes to find the bunde.js of the previous build and this is the reason why also my the styles of tsx/jsx are honored. The output is perfectly optimized.
3. If I follow PurifiyCSS' [hint for CSS modules](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/purifycss-webpack#usage-with-css-modules) I get this output:

   PurifyCSS has reduced the file size by ~ 1.5%

   and the page is also correctly rendered. But all styles (used and unused) are included and the package size is much bigger. Only a couple of bytes smaller than without PurifyCSS.

My question now is:
How can I achieve to get the output of "2." even on the first build run? It seems the output is not serialized anywhere and so I can't tell PurifyCSS to take it into account.

Has anyone solved this problem? I couldn't find anything on the web.

Thx,
Stephan

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I also posted here https://github.com/webpack-contrib/purifycss-webpack/issues/127 but the answer was not satisfying